# How do I store the contents of an array to a json file in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I wanted to save the contents of an array to a .json file.The array has some dictionaries in it. I tried

```
Set-Content -Path 'crl_urls.json' -Value $arrayval -Force
```

The JSON file has stored `System.Collections.Hashtable`. It hasn't stored the values of the dictionaries.

So How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly save the content in a .json file you should first convert the array to the .json format.
Try this:

```
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $arrayval | Out-File -FilePath .\crl_urls.json
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet I was able to export the contents of the array in the JSON file.
Example Code:

```
Set-Content -Path 'crl_urls1.json' -Value ($arrayval|ConvertTo-Json) -Force
```